# Why is my index [4] out of range when there are 4 items in my list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

my error:

if player_order_chooser[4] == player_a:
IndexError: list index out of range

```
>import random
> 
>player_a = "Joe" 
>player_b = "john" 
>player_c = "Donald" 
>player_d = "Brady"
> 
> 
>player_order_chooser = [player_a,player_b,player_c,player_d]
>random.shuffle(player_order_chooser) 
>x = len(player_order_chooser)
>print(x)
>print(player_order_chooser[1]) 
>print(player_order_chooser[2])
>print(player_order_chooser[3]) 
>print(player_order_chooser[4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index of array/list starts from 0 instead of 1.

If you have array of length 4, that's mean it has values stored in indexes from 0 to 3.

In your example, without using:

```
random.shuffle(player_order_chooser)
```

In order to print "Joe" which is stored in string player_a:

```
>print(player_order_chooser[0])
```

While, in order to print "Brady" which is stored in string player_d:

```
>print(player_order_chooser[3])
```

After using random.shuffle() the results will change but the size of index remains the same.